# Why are my images getting corrupted in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a netbook running as a server for some web development I do. It's running Ubuntu.

Whenever I put images on it, they get corrupted and do not display correctly.
I've viewed them properly on OSX and Windows; neither of which say they are corrupted.

Firefox is telling me "Image corrupt or truncated" ... here is a screen shot. top left is the way it should look, bottom right is the way the netbook is serving the images.

[image]
Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: How are you determining the corruption?

Comment: What sort of images are they? Could you provide a sample, preferably both before and after corruption?

Comment: Firefox is telling me "Image corrupt or truncated" ... here is a screen shot.  top left is the way it should look, bottom right is the way the netbook is serving the images:  http://tinypic.com/r/294lx7c/5

Comment: Are you putting the images on your netbook through FTP?  Be sure you're in BINARY mode.

Comment: I've tried FTP in Binary, wget via SSH, and manually dropping them into a folder as a shared drive.

Comment: Can we please get the hardware specifications of that Netbook? Also, how is it connected to your network? Are the files corrupted the moment you copy them onto the Netbook or when you get them off?

Comment: *get* the image via wget/ssh, and look at them locally. Look at the images on the server. Check that the web server isn't somehow mangling the files or announcing the wrong format.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. How did you manage to fix the corrupted images ?